# Encoding bytes result is very short

Tags: c#

I created a bitmap screenshot:

```
Bitmap screenshot = TakeScreenshot();
byte[] bytes = ImageToByte(screenshot, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Now I try to encode it:

```
string imageData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

However, if I output this string in my rich textbox then all I get as result is this:

```
BM6�~
```

Even though the length of `imageData` is **8277082**

What is going on?

---

**Functions:**

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{
    using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream()) {
        img.Save(stream, format);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}

private Bitmap TakeScreenshot()
{
    //Create a new bitmap.
    var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                   Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                                   System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    // Create a graphics object from the bitmap. (geht auch ohne das using gedöns, aber mit using ist es besser)
    using (var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot)) {
        // Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner.
        gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                0,
                                0,
                                Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                                CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    }

    return bmpScreenshot;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by converting basically array of RGB `bytes` to `string`?

Comment: Turning it into UTF8 won't make the text human readable.  You're going to get a lot of garbage, including null characters, which the textbox won't handle.  `BM` is the UTF8 preamble for BMP images.

Comment: @Dusan Vanna, I try to transfer it to a webserver where I try to recreate the image out of it and store it

Comment: If you need to transfer to server, best would be to use base-64 encoding which will create string longer than your bytes but it will be transport-safe.

Comment: Thank you so much @all, im still a beginner at c# and you guys helped me alot to understand this

Comment: @Dusan if you did not know, the exact size it makes it longer is by 4/3. (+ up to 2 bytes depending on if the resulting string is evenly divisible by 3)

Comment: @Scott Yes, I knew that, but exact 4/3 is only when number of bytes is divisible by 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` on something that does not actually represent a string. the encoding fails (like you have seen), you need to use a encoding that can handle arbitrary bytes like Base 64 encoding

```
string imageData = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

on the server to get the bytes back you use

```
byte[] imageDataAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageDataAsString);
```

One thing to note, using base 64 encoding will cause the string to take up 4/3 the original size in bytes. If possible try to investigate if you can just send a raw byte[] to the server instead of encoding it in a string first, this will make less data be transferred.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to represent binary data in a string, but a string can't represent every binary data.

If you want a string then you need to use some form of encoding being the most common Base64.

Change

```
string imageData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

To

```
string imageData = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Remember, to restore the original binary data you must decode it:

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
```

Comment: All answered the same, but you answered first - so +1 to you buddy.

Answer (score 5):

It is wrong to encode binary data into string like this, instead you must use `Convert.ToBase64String()` to get text representation that can be converted back to bytes.

Comment: Strings are *NOT* null terminated in C#, this is totally fine: `var h = "Hello\0World"; System.Console.WriteLine($"String: {h}, Length: {h.Length}");`

Comment: @NikontheThird Hmm.. I wonder why it does not display more characters..

Comment: Because he tried to convert arbitrary binary data (which almost certainly is not a valid UTF8 encoding) to a UTF8 string. The UTF8 conversion fails once it reaches invalid codepoints and just returns what it has so far.

Answer (score 4):

This

```
string imageData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

...only works when `bytes` contains a UTF8-encoded string. Otherwise you will get garbage.

If you want to store an image as a string, consider encoding it in BASE64 instead:

```
string imageData = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```